# A simple on-circuit RS-232 to USB converter

Tags: pic, usb, serial

I want to interface a PIC microcontroller ([18f452](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en010296)) to a PC via the USB port. I learned that there is a USB class for serial communication so I will not have to write device drivers for it.

I want to know a simple way to connect my PIC to a USB port. I prefer a one IC circuit.
Is there an IC that will do my job?

Comment: The USB class for serial communications is not supported on Windows XP, so you need third-party drivers anyway. I'd say that using FTDI chips and their drivers is a decent way of going about it. The more recent FT230X chips are a nice choice IMHO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [FT232R](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf) mentioned by Toby is the standard solution. [FTDI](http://www.ftdichip.com) has become the main supplier of USB connection solutions for microcontrollers and other logic devices. You install a Vitual COM Driver on your PC (downloadable from the FTDI website) and then you use the USB as a transparent communication channel for your UART. Means that the PIC will only see UART in and out, and the PC software will think the PIC is connected to a serial COM port.

[image]

This is the minimum configuration. As you can see that it's hardly more than the IC and the USB connector.

[image]

A breakout board like this one only needs ground Tx and Rx connections with the microcontroller. If necessary it can also provide the power supply for it.

**edit**
*m.Alin* mentions the Microchip [MCP2200](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22228B.pdf) as an alternative to the FT232R. I didn't know the device, and only had a quick look at the datasheet, but it looks promising: only half the price of the FT232R, and has both UART and GPIO. Breakout boards available:

[image]

(I'll study the datasheet a bit more tomorrow and report back.)

Comment: Well, actually it is claimed that MCP2200 is recognized as PIC18F14K50, and cheaper than a blank PIC. [source](http://dangerousprototypes.com/2011/01/18/hack-open-source-usb-stack-on-mcp2200/)

Comment: Updated link to MCP2200 datasheet: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22228A.pdf

Answer (score 10):

The [FT232L](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT232R.htm) is a popular choice. It has drivers for all the main operating systems.
There are [breakout boards](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/718?) available.

Comment: For a cheaper alternative, see [MCP2200](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en546923)

Comment: @m.Alin - Thanks for the tip. Checked the datasheet only briefly, but looks good. Only half the price of the FT232R, and has both UART and GPIO.

Comment: @stevenvh Interesting fact about the MCP2200 is that it's actually a pre-programmed PIC18F14K50

Comment: The MCP2200 is half the price of a FT232R, but needs an external crystal.  The FT230X is about the same price as the MCP2200 and includes internal clock generation like the other FTDI chips.

Answer (score 7):

The [MicroFTX](http://jim.sh/ftx) would do what you want.  It's an extremely tiny breakout board for FTDI's new lower-cost [FT230X](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT230X.html) USB to serial chip.  There are solder jumpers on the bottom that let you configure things like I/O voltage and power options.

[image: MicroFTX top]

[image: MicroFTX bottom]

Comment: That design is a bit cavalier with ignoring the EMI choke on VBUS, and the 47pF impedance-matching capacitors on the DP/DM lines on the chip side. I'd not use it outside of the lab. Heck, for any production device using FTDI chips I'd in fact put both a USB differential choke on the data lines and a USB ESD protection. Those are all fairly tiny devices.

Comment: It's only for the X-series chips that we get any ESD details at all, FT232R's datasheet is mum about it. For 232R I'd add USB ESD protection (say [USBLC6](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00050750.pdf)).

Comment: Agreed, this design has not been tested for EMI/FCC compliance, or USB spec compliance.  FTDI provides [hardware design guidelines](http://www.ftdichip.com/Documents/AppNotes/AN_146_USB_Hardware_Design_Guidelines_for_FTDI_ICs.pdf) that have a number of useful tips to follow for production devices.  Those guidelines mention that all FTDI devices are tested for ESD protection to 2.5KV-3KV, and that things like capacitors to ground on DP/DM are optional and should be adjusted as needed during USB compliance testing.  The 27Ω series termination is always required, so this board includes it.